# Bcp command is getting error Out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I need to export the Json data into a text file, but it is getting error out.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT Formdata fldr.FormInstanceDataMap WHERE 
FormInstanceID=127432" queryout "D:\Import\Test.txt" -
STMGVM021\deBenefitSync_Web_DEV -T -c -Usa -Psa@123 '
```

Getting error Out. Output is

> Copy direction must be either 'in' or 'out'. Syntax Error in
>   'queryout'. usage: bcp [[db_name.]owner.]table_name[:slice_num]
>   [partition pname] {in |  out} [filename] [-m maxerrors] [-f
>   formatfile] [-e errfile] [-d discardfileprefix]  [-F firstrow] [-L
>   lastrow] [-b batchsize] [-n] [-c] [-t field_terminator] [-r
>   row_terminator] [-U username] [-P password] [-I interfaces_file] [-S
>   server] [-a display_charset] [-z language] [-v] [-i input_file] [-o
>   output_file]  [-A packet size] [-J client character set]  [-T text or
>   image size] [-E] [-g id_start_value] [-N] [-W] [-X] [-M LabelName
>   LabelValue] [-labeled] [-K keytab_file] [-R remote_server_principal]
>   [-C] [-V [security_options]] [-Z security_mechanism] [-Q] [-Y] [-y
>   sybase directory] [-x trusted.txt_file] [--clienterr errfile]
>   [--maxconn maximum_connections] [--show-fi] [--hide-vcc] [--colpasswd
>   [[[db_name.[owner].]table_name.]column_name [password]]] [--keypasswd
>   [[db_name.[owner].]key_name [password]]] [--initstring ASE
>   initialization string] [--quoted-fname] NULL

Comment: I guess the `-S Servername\instancename` needs to be fixed, by looking at your example - `-STMGVM021\deBenefitSync_Web_DEV` you need a space between `-S` and `Servername\instancename`

Comment: Should queryout be just out? See the usage: line in the error - it says you need to specify in or out on the command line.

Comment: I tried it again by aplying space between -S and servername\instancename but still it's error out with same error message.

Comment: Also when `–T` specified, you don't need to specify `–U` and `–P` to successfully log in.

Comment: @Ashu - please edit your question with the final `bcp` query, it would help.

Comment: EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT Formdata fldr.FormInstanceDataMap WHERE FormInstanceID=127432" queryout "D:\Import\Test.txt" -
S TMGVM021\deBenefitSync_Web_DEV -T -c  ' i tried mentioned query but still its shows same error.

Comment: @Ashu --are you sure the query is well built, does the below query work independently. `SELECT Formdata fldr.FormInstanceDataMap WHERE FormInstanceID=127432`

Comment: yes. query is work independently properly.

Comment: It should give `Incorrect syntax near '.'` - as I don't see any table name specified

Comment: You are **NOT** using the bcp utility provided by sql server. Guessing it is from Sybase. And as others have already indicated, your query is not valid sql and it contains parameters that the sybase version does not support.

Answer (score 0):

I could find two changes in your query.

1. When -T (windows authentication) option is added, no need to specify the SQL credentials.
2. You did not specify the DB name. Unless the needed DB is specified as default in your login, then probably you might end up with error.

Thanks,
Ananda Kumar J.